# How to export nested json array to pdf using PDFMAKE Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, pdfmake

I have used Angular as programming language for my project and i am a beginner. But i am stuck at the point where i have to generate PDF of my JSON response.

Looked at the documentation of PDFMAKE to achieve the same, but couldnot figure out how to implement it and come out with the output as shown in following image.

[Output Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNqLG.png)

The JSON response is as follows:

```
{
    "statusCode": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "partyId": 1,
            "partyIdDisp": "1/PA/2077",
            "createdDate": "2077/05/03",
            "partyName": "Roshan Basnet",
            "contactNumber": 9841040791,
            "companyName": "Butwal Poultry",
            "panNumber": 321654,
            "address": "Butwal, Nepal",
            "saleDetails": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f5b234cbac67e377c2a700f",
                    "saleId": 1,
                    "saleIdDisp": "1/S/2077",
                    "createdDate": "2077/05/26",
                    "saleType": "Credit",
                    "customerId": 1,
                    "customerName": "Roshan Basnet",
                    "contactNumber": 9841040791,
                    "billingName": "Butwal Poultry",
                    "billingAddress": "Butwal, Nepal",
                    "billDate": "2077/05/26",
                    "itemDetails": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5b234cbac67e377c2a7010",
                            "itemId": 1,
                            "itemName": "Chicken",
                            "quantity": 10,
                            "unit": "KG",
                            "piece": 5,
                            "receiptNo": null,
                            "billNo": 366,
                            "unitPrice": 310,
                            "itemAmount": 3100
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalQuantity": 10,
                    "paymentMethod": "Cash",
                    "subTotal": 3100,
                    "amountInWords": "three thousand one hundred only",
                    "outstandingBalance": 0,
                    "receivedAmount": 3000,
                    "balanceAmount": 100,
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f5b2375bac67e377c2a7012",
                    "saleId": 2,
                    "saleIdDisp": "2/S/2077",
                    "createdDate": "2077/05/26",
                    "saleType": "Credit",
                    "customerId": 1,
                    "customerName": "Roshan Basnet",
                    "contactNumber": 9841040791,
                    "billingName": "Butwal Poultry",
                    "billingAddress": "Butwal, Nepal",
                    "billDate": "2077/05/26",
                    "itemDetails": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5b2375bac67e377c2a7013",
                            "itemId": 2,
                            "itemName": "Mutton",
                            "quantity": 5,
                            "unit": "KG",
                            "piece": 0,
                            "receiptNo": null,
                            "billNo": 266,
                            "unitPrice": 1200,
                            "itemAmount": 6000
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f5b2375bac67e377c2a7014",
                            "itemId": 3,
                            "itemName": "Eggs",
                            "quantity": 10,
                            "unit": "Crate",
                            "piece": 0,
                            "receiptNo": null,
                            "billNo": 366,
                            "unitPrice": 390,
                            "itemAmount": 3900
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalQuantity": 15,
                    "paymentMethod": "Cash",
                    "subTotal": 10000,
                    "amountInWords": "ten thousand only",
                    "outstandingBalance": 100,
                    "receivedAmount": 5000,
                    "balanceAmount": 5000,
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

A code snippet how to generate a pdf output as per the structure in the image would be helpful.

Comment: Please use markup to make your question more readable.

Comment: @MikayelSaghyan I have formatted the question. Please check and let me know if more elaboration required to make it readable.

Comment: Please use the code text option to make it more visible !